# scale image down to fit mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

While trying to make a mobile version of a website I made I ran into the issue of image sizing for mobile devices. Is there a method to reliably make the image fluid to whatever size the browser is at? My current image causes the screen to have extra space to the right(which only has the rest of the image).

I've tried width: 100%
max-width:100%

and neither seem to be working (although they seem to be the solution when I look at similar questions) - can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Someone made a request for only the related code - I'm not sure if this is actually the problem or not, but I think it is this:

HTML:

```
<div id="images">
                <img src="images/cristina.png" alt="Cristina Lord">
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

    body{text-align: center;}
    div#content{text-align: center;}
    div#eventtext{text-align: center;
        padding-left: 13.2%}
    div#line{width: 100%;}
    div#center{
        padding-left: 0%;
    }
    div#images{
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

The rest is still here, for reference.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Cristina Lord</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="site_title1">
            Cristina Lord
        </div>
        <div id="site_title2">
            Composer, Pianist
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="images">
            <img src="images/cristina.png" alt="Cristina Lord">
        </div>  
        <div id="about">
            <p>Cristina is currently a senior at the University of California, Santa Barbara, where she is completing her B.A. degree in Music Composition at the College of Creative Studies. She will be pursuing her masters at Cal State Long Beach in the fall. While at UCSB, she has studied composition under William Kraft, Dr. Leslie Hogan, and Dr. Jeremy Haladyna, piano with Dr. Charles Asche, and conducting with Christopher Rountree.</p>
            <br>    
            <p>Cristina has worked as a piano teacher for the Santa Barbara School of Music for the past three years. She also regularly sings for the English Broadside Ballad Archive at UCSB, and is a member of the contemporary choral ensemble New Century Voices.</p>
            <br>    
            <p>Last year (2013), Cristina won a Corwin Award in the vocal category for her song cycle, Songs of American Women, which will be performed this year by the Ensemble for Contemporary Music and at the Primavera Festival at UCSB.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <footer>
            <p>Copyright Cristina Lord 2014 &copy;</p>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/cristina.lord"><img src="images/facebooklogo.png" height="40" width="40" alt="Facebook"></a>
            <a href="http://www.soundcloud.com/cristina_lord"><img src="images/soundcloudlogo.png" height="40" width="76" alt="SoundCloud"></a>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
    */

    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
    body {
    line-height: 1;
}
    ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
    blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
    table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}



    /* main font style, background color, and body margins */


    body{
    background-color: rgb(255,255,240);
    color:black;
    font-family: "Calibri", "Candara", "Segoe", "Segoe UI", "Optima", "Arial", sans-serif;
    xpadding: 45px 100px 0px 100px;
    padding: 45px 7.8125% 0% 7.8125%;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 20px;

}

    /* main header style */

    div#site_title1 
    {
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

    div#site_title2
    {
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

    /*menu style*/

    div#menu ul a
    {
    color:black;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
    border-color: rgb(255,255,240);

}

    div#menu li
    {   display: inline;
}

    div#menu ul a:hover
    {
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #BC8F8F;
    transition: border-color 0.5s ease;

}

    div#menu
    {word-spacing:5px;}

    #menu, #menu a {
    padding:10px 10px 20px 10px;

}

    div#menu li.selected a { color:rgb(188,143,143);border-bottom: 2px solid #BC8F8F;} 


/* about and image positioning */

    div#about
    {
    max-width:500px;
    font-size: 16px;
      -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 0.5s;
    }

    div#images
    {
    float:right;
    padding-right: 7.8125%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
      -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 0.5s;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* event headers and text */

    div#eventheader
    {
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    div#eventsubheader
    {
    color:#000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    div#eventtext
    {
    color:black;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    max-width:400px;
}

/* table positioning/style */

    th{
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    width:250px;
}

    td{
    padding:1%;
    width:250px;
}

    div#tablelist{
    color:#000;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
}

    #tablelist, #tablelist a {
padding-left:20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
xpadding-left:1.5625%;
xpadding-right: 1.5625%;
xpadding-bottom: 1.5625%;
}

    table {
    padding-left: 25px;
}

/* footer style */


    html,
    body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
    #wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position: relative;
}
    #content {
    padding-bottom:70px;  
    overflow: auto;
}
    #footer {

    border-top: 2px solid rgb(188,143,143);
    bottom:0;
    height:70px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}

    body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


    /*fadein*/

    div#contenttext{
       -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 0.5s;
}

    div#musiccontent{
      -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 0.5s;
}

    div#eventcontent{
       -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 0.5s;
}

    /* Firefox */
    @-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}​

/* Opera */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}​


/* misc. */

div#floatleft{
    float:left;
}

div#floatright{
    float: right;
}


a {text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
        transition: color 0.5s ease;

    }

a:hover {color:rgb(188,143,143);}


div#line{
    width:33.3333%;
}

div#center{
    padding-left:7.03125%;
}


/**media queries **/


@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

    body{text-align: center;}
    div#content{text-align: center;}
    div#eventtext{text-align: center;
        padding-left: 13.2%}
    div#line{width: 100%;}
    div#center{
        padding-left: 0%;
    }
    div#images{
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

It starts become an issue at around 250-300% zoom on a 1280 X 800 screen if you don't have a mobile device. Hopefully I've explained this well, thanks for reading this.

website: http://cristinalord.com

Comment: You should better share only the related code, its easy for us to check the problem. Otherwise we'll have to find the problem too. :-) Thanks!

Comment: There are several ways of doing this:1. Use media query to break at different device widths; 2. remove padding-right for #menu; 3. set min-width for your image so that it goes on top of the text when screen width is too small

Comment: Your padding outside of the #image div is causing the issue probably. is the screen kinda sliding, or the image not position where you would expect? Changes are that you just need to pull the padding for the div and divs containing it to nothing, or remove it from containers to see if your rules work this way

Comment: Brett, I believe the issue is that the image is too big, and min-width or width don't seem to fix it. The screen is sliding in a weird way - everything else is 100% visible except for the image. You have to slide to the left to see the remainder of it, but nothing else is visible there. Zoom in a few times on the website and that will show you the issue I'm talking about. Thanks for taking the time to answer this!